geo coordinates to relative position on downloaded satellite image
I have a bounding box coordinates that I use to download the satellite image from Bing. I have polygon coordinates inside the previous bounding box.
Is it possible to get the corresponding polygon coordinates in pixels so that I can locate them in the downloaded image?
Here is one way I tried doing it: I would convert the polygon coordinates to their respective pixel coordinates, considering the bounding box are the limitation, applying the following (point_lat, point_lon are the coordinates for one point of the polygon:
    px = round((point_lon-boundingbox["minLon"])*image_width/(boundingbox["maxLon"] - boundingbox["minLon"])) 
    
    py = round((point_lat-boundingbox["maxLat"])*image_height/(boundingbox["minLat"] - boundingbox["maxLat"]))))

and I get something like the following:

Which doesn't match the limitation I made in software exactly, for example, my polygon was defined at the road's limit and doesn't include part of the building next to it... So I'm assuming this conversion is too simplified and the error is big.
Is there a better way of doing this?
I'm using Bing for the satelite imagery and I have a front-end interface using leafletjs to draw the polygon and obtain the coordinates for the bounding box and the polygon

It's nice to see you added more detail this time you asked the same question. You need to account for the cell size of the raster. Again, is the downloaded raster georeferenced? If so what coordinate reference system is it in? What coordinate reference system are your points in? In a georeferenced raster the origin is usually top, I can't say I've ever seen a raster that isn't top,left origin ,left so to go to cell space it's (pointX - left) / CellSizeX = column, (top - pointY) / abs(CellSizeY) = row provided that the raster and points are in the same coordinate reference system.

from my understanding of georeferenced, this one isn't. The way it was obtained was using bing maps API, and takes bounding box coordinates... I'm going to check if it's possible to get metadata which could be useful here. I think both the raster and the points are using the same coordinate system

the coordinates reference system used is EPSG:3857

For both the coordinates and the raster? GDAL is a lib available in python that can extract the origin and cell size in a GeoTransform array (6 doubles) https://gdal.org/tutorials/geotransforms_tut.html, I'm sure I've got some code lying around that transforms X,Y into Row,Col using GDAL.
